# PHP - SESSION not registering

Tags: php

I tried to make admin panel and I am using `sessions` , but have problem, session does not work,

## index.php

```
$r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$login=$r["login"];
session_register('login');
Header("Location: protected.php");
```

## protected.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) { 
  echo "Not work";
}
else{
  echo "Work";
}
?>
```

I do not know what the problem is, because in index.php I register session, but in protected.php this session is not set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `session_register()`. It was removed in PHP 5.4.0.
In index.php, add `session_start();` to the top and replace your register call with `$_SESSION['login'] = 'val';`

Comment: what is different between $_SESSION['login'] and $_SESSION["login"] ?

Comment: None, in your case. Using single quotes means that PHP won't parse variables within the text, so you can do something like 'hi $foo' and it will remain literally that. With double quotes, "hi $foo" will become hi followed by the value of $foo. There's more to it than that, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of [session_register()](https://www.php.net/session_register) is deprecated as of 5.3.0, and has not been recommended since 4.1.0.

Instead, create the session variable using [$_SESSION[]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) in the same format that you reference it:

```
$_SESSION['login'] = $r["login"];
```

Utilizing this approach removes the need to initialize the `$login` variable as the login value from your result set is set directly to the session variable.

```
<?php // Use of session_register() is deprecated 
$barney = "A big purple dinosaur."; session_register("barney");

// Use of $_SESSION is preferred, as of PHP 4.1.0 
$_SESSION["zim"] = "An invader from another planet.";

// The old way was to use $HTTP_SESSION_VARS 
$HTTP_SESSION_VARS["spongebob"] = "He's got square pants."; ?>
```

In addition, it is recommended that [`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) not be used and instead, [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions should be utilized.

Answer (score 2):

`session_register()` is deprecated, read here for more information:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php